# Getting HR lines above and below bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap carousel to display a load of images, and I use the carousel indicators as image icons. I would like to have a HR line appear above and below these icons. How should I go about this?

Currently the icons as carousel indicators works great; and it appears below the main carousel; however if I add a hr tag above and below the indicators block of code, they appear above the image carousel. I have tried wrapping the indicators code block in a div with a hr tag above and below but this also doesn't work.

```
  <div class="carousel-image">
     <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">


        <hr id="topLine">
           <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              @foreach( $album->photos as $photo )
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="carousel-image-indicator {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
                 <img src="/storage/photos/{{$photo->album_id}}/{{$photo->photo}}" alt="{{$photo->title}}" width="180">
              </li>
              @endforeach
           </ol>
        <hr id="baseLine">


        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
           @foreach( $album->photos as $photo )
           <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="/storage/photos/{{$photo->album_id}}/{{$photo->photo}}" alt="{{ $photo->title }}">
           </div>
           @endforeach
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

This does use Laravel to populate the carousel, and that is working. This is the code for my carousel, the HR tags are the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use border-top and border-bottom instead. Carousel indicators are positioned absolutely. So hr cant reference for carousel indicators

Comment: Thanks a lot; I didn't even think of that!

Comment: Always think border first... The real world use cases for `<hr>` are pretty scarce.

Comment: Yeah I haven't done any webdev in a few years, I'll mark as solved when I'm allowed to

Comment: If you want to add space, just add padding